# jitpack not resolving libraries

Tags: android, gradle

Everything was working fine I almost created half of the project and suddenly got the gradle error of libraries due to jitpack . when I added  url "https://maven.google.com" in my gradle file it solves the library problem but getting error for materialsearch bar . Here is my gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
                maven{
                    url "https://jitpack.io"
                }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Error
Failed to Resolve compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'

Answer (score 0):

try update your dependencies to 
   `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'`
  `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'`

and all project repositores

```
   allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}
```

if you still have erros then edit the question and add the error

Comment: go to your project build.gradle and try `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'` also read (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies)

Comment: I have old android studio so implementation doesn't work

Comment: yeh, you have update your android studio, and also try to remove the + in `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'` because it causes erros sometimes